# Cannot copy/paste anymore in tmux 2.1

Tags: macos, terminal, tmux

I just update to tmux 2.1(OS X10.11.3 Terminal.app),  and my .tmux.conf（accroding to http://joehanchoi.com/quick-fixes-for-tmux-2-1-on-osx/）

```
set-option -g mouse on
bind -n WheelUpPane if-shell -F -t = "#{mouse_any_flag}" "send-keys -M" "if -Ft= '#{pane_in_mode}' 'send-keys -M' 'select-pane -t=; copy-mode -e; send-keys -M'"  
bind -n WheelDownPane select-pane -t= \; send-keys -M
```

but the problem is after I start tmux, the mouse pointer becomes a plus: `+`， and I cannot copy/paste anymore.
And right click on Terminal does not work, no popups

How to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two factors:

- Terminal.app in *El Capitan* recognizes (some of) xterm's escape sequences for the mouse.
- tmux 2.1 has some changes — for the (xterm) mouse protocol

This was discussed extensively in  [*Mouse scrolling in tmux 2.1 on OSX no longer auto-starts #145*](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/issues/145) , but no one suggested a different configuration than the one you are using.